# Display data in dropdown lists from another file (php,mysql,javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I got multiple database dropdown lists with javascript, and I want to display result in dropdown menu. But at this moment, nothing shows. It shows Regions (drop down menu), but dosn't show Countries (drop down menu)

My Core Code(I want to display result in Country drop down menu):

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc(){
        var e = document.getElementById("Region_ID");
        var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        $.post("getSecondDropDown.php",{ Region_ID:val}, function( data ) {
        $("#Country_ID").html(data);

    });
 }
 </script>


<form action="/NewService.php" id="ServiceForm" method="post">
  Name:<input type="text" name="Service_Name"></br>
  Region: <select name="Region_ID" id="Region_ID" onchange="abc()" form="ServiceForm">
 <?php

include('config.php');

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Region_ID, Region_Name FROM Regions"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $v['Region_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Region_Name'] ."</option>";

}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
</select></br>


Country: <select name="Country_ID" form="ServiceForm">
<script>document.write($("#Country_ID"))</script>
</select></br>


  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Second php file(getSecondDropDownMenu.php):

```
<?php
    $Region_ID =$_POST['Region_ID'];
    $option="";
              try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Country_ID, Country_Name FROM Countries WHERE Region_ID ='$Region_ID'"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 

    echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";

}
        echo $option;
  ?>
```

I Think that problem is here, but don't really know it :

```
Country: <select name="Country_ID" form="ServiceForm">
<script>document.write($("#Country_ID"))</script>
</select></br>
```

Comment: Add id attribute to select tag.

Comment: @JobinSKumar Still nothing.

Comment: @crelix1234 I have updated my answer. Have a check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second file ( getSecondDropDownMenu ) you need to create a function

```
<?php
function functionName(){
$Region_ID =$_POST['Region_ID'];
$option[] = null;
          try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Country_ID, Country_Name FROM Countries WHERE Region_ID ='$Region_ID'"); 
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

foreach($stmt as $v) { 

array_push($option,  "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>");

     }
  return option;
  }
?>
```

Then in the other file the first one include it 
   include('getSecondDropDownMenu.php');

and do

```
$arrayForSecondDropdown[] = functionName();
```

and then do the foreach like

```
 foreach($arrayForSecondDropdown as $v){
      echo $v;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I did something like this : Country: <select name="Country_ID" id="Country_ID" form="ServiceForm">
<?php
include('config.php');
include_once('getSecondDropDownMenu.php');

$arrayForSecondDropdown[] = functionName();
$foreach($arrayForSecondDropdown[] as $v){
       echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";
}
?>
</select></br>

Comment: But it shows : Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in line : $foreach($arrayForSecondDropdown[] as $v){

Comment: @crelix1234 take the [] away before the as $v my bad and also you can echo the $v inside an dropdown because you already return the <option></option>

Comment: Tried to do it, but then it shows another error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS) in (same line). Sorry if this is simple question, I just can't get trought this problem for a weeks.

Comment: @crelix1234 there is a dollar sign in front of your foreach

Comment: Thanks, i did all like you said, but it seems to shown nothing again. : http://imgur.com/a/zPDn6

Comment: It's not finding the other file ? are they in the same folder? No typos? You can also try a normal include

Comment: @crelix1234 It can't connect to the database now after that It should be good

Comment: Now got error in developer console (sources) : Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory<option value=''></option></select></br

Comment: @crelix1234 It cant connect to the database because you didnt include include('config.php'); in the getSecondDropDown menu file

Comment: I have included it, in this topic code just didn't edited it. http://imgur.com/a/24HbV

Comment: @crelix1234 Have you included it in the getSecondDropDownMenu.php ?

Comment: Since it returns <option value =" and more it should be good now but I don't know about that error you can try to take the Include away and do it i nthe file itself like take the values out of the config.php and put it in the getSecondDropDownMenu directly

Comment: But the rest of the code should be good now you only have a connection error now I think

Comment: Tried to do it, but same. Maybe problem are before <option> tag? somewhere here? Image : http://imgur.com/a/leNQT Becouse error are showed before option tag.

Comment: you only need to have echo $v; in the foreach loop but im not sure that will fix your PDO error

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `abc` function by calling it with `onchange='abc(this.value)'` and the target dropdown requires an ID attribute to enable the callback to add the html data. Also, as you are not passing any variables to the sql statement you do not really require the prepared statement, a simple `query` should suffice.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dependant select menu</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function abc( value ){
                    $.post("getSecondDropDown.php",{ Region_ID:value }, function( data ) {
                        $("#Country_ID").html( data );
                    }
                );
             }
         </script>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/NewService.php" id="ServiceForm" method="post">
          Name:<input type="text" name="Service_Name"></br>
          Region: <select name="Region_ID" id="Region_ID" onchange="abc( this.value )" form="ServiceForm">

             <?php

                include('config.php');

                try {

                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT Region_ID, Region_Name FROM Regions" ); 
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 

                    foreach($stmt as $v) { 
                        echo "<option value='" . $v['Region_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Region_Name'] ."</option>";
                    }
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
                $conn = null;

            ?>
            </select>
            </br>

            Country: <select id='Country_ID' name="Country_ID" form="ServiceForm"></select>
            </br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the code to display with the help of ID for the select tag but you have not been given any `ID` for the `select tag`

```
<script>document.write($("#Country_ID"))</script>
```

As per the script you have provided you have to add an `ID Attribute` for the select tag.

I would recommend not using `document.write`, especially after the page has loaded. It can lead to unexpected results. Just use this method:

Try Replacing with this:

```
document.getElementById('Country_ID').innerHTML = "something important";
```

If however, you are not  willing to replace the whole innerHTML, you could append something to it:

```
document.getElementById('Country_ID').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "something added");
```

Comment: Thanks another time, but still nope, it don't work, will try something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missed the config file to include in your Second php file(getSecondDropDownMenu.php):. So the scripts in this is not able to run. Why this happens means this page is able to get **database connection** .ou are fetching the country list from database on the basis of region so here no database connection is achieved.So please **include config.php** and try again.And also you have done another mistake in **concatenation of php variable with the string** .IE in the country fetching query you should concatenate the region variable with correct syntax.Please see the below code.

**Second php file(getSecondDropDownMenu.php):**

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $Region_ID =$_POST['Region_ID'];
    $option="";
              try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Country_ID, Country_Name FROM Countries WHERE Region_ID ='".$Region_ID."'"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 

    echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";

}
        echo $option;
  ?>
```

I think this may help you.